# JavaFX fit an image in a toggleButton

Tags: javafx

I have the following code

```java
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("1.png").toExternalForm(), tg.getWidth(), tg.getHeight(), false, true, true);
ImageView view = new ImageView(img);
tg.setGraphic(view);
```

(where `tg` is a toggle button)

and I get this [image]

I want the image to fit perfectly into the button but whatever I do I'm unable to accomplish this. I've already tried using `view.setFit` methods but it doesn't seem to have any effect

Edit:

This is the code that creates the GridPane

```
this.gameBoard = new GridPane();
this.gameBoard.setPrefSize(600, 600);
this.gameCards = new ToggleButton[this.boardSize * this.boardSize];
EventHandler<ActionEvent> cardSelectedHandler = this::onCardSelected;
for (int i = 0; i < this.gameCards.length; i++) {
    this.gameCards[i] = new ToggleButton;
    this.gameCards[i].setPrefSize(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
    this.gameCards[i].setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    this.gameCards[i].setOnAction(cardSelectedHandler);
    this.gameBoard.add(this.gameCards[i], i % this.boardSize, i / this.boardSize);
    GridPane.setHgrow(this.gameCards[i], Priority.ALWAYS);
    GridPane.setVgrow(this.gameCards[i], Priority.ALWAYS);
}

private void onCardSelected(ActionEvent event) {
    ToggleButton tg = (ToggleButton) event.getTarget();
    Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("1.png").toExternalForm(), tg.getWidth(), tg.getHeight(), false, true, true);
    ImageView view = new ImageView(img);
    tg.setGraphic(view);
```

EDIT 2:
doing some change

```java
private void onCardSelected(ActionEvent event) {
    ToggleButton tg = (ToggleButton) event.getTarget();
    Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("1.png").toExternalForm());
    ImageView view = new ImageView(img);
    view.setFitHeight(150);
    view.setFitWidth(150);
    view.setPreserveRatio(false);
    tg.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    tg.setGraphic(view);
```

I now get [image]

but I still get this button resize

Comment: Read the [tips for sizing nodes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/size_align.htm#JFXLY133) (twice).  Don’t set the max size for the buttons (it makes them grow to fit  available space).

Comment: You also set grid pane h and v grow constraints on the buttons, I am not sure why.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do.  Do you actually want the buttons to resize? If so how should the image behave in such a circumstance?

Comment: @jewelsea I copied the grid pane creation code from a tic tac toe example it's probably not good/suitable for this scenario